# Laravel: Problem with markbaker/complex package & Composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

**I'm a beginner in Laravel,** I have installed [Laravel Excel packeage](https://laravel-excel.com/) in my project successfully. but, there is a problem appear with the package, when I run `composer update` it shows this error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Nothing to modify in lock file
> Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
> Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Installing markbaker/complex (2.0.0): Extracting archive
- Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.13.0): Extracting archive
  Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: require(D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer/../markbaker/complex/classes/src/functions/abs.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:71
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(71): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(C:\User...', 'C:\Users\Mukhta...', 71, Array)
> #1 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(71): require()
> #2 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(61): composerRequiredc8412b933c3488a0bbfad0ab059a147('abede361264e2ae...', 'C:\Users\Mukhta...')
> #3 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitdc8412b933c3488a0bbfad0ab059a147::getLoader()
> #4  in D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71
> Warning: Uncaught ErrorException: require(D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer/../markbaker/complex/classes/src/functions/abs.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:71
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(71): Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'require(C:\User...', 'D:\projects\my_project...', 71, Array)
> #1 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(71): require()
> #2 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(61): composerRequiredc8412b933c3488a0bbfad0ab059a147('abede361264e2ae...', 'D:\projects\my_project...')
> #3 D:\projects\my_project\vendor\autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitdc8412b933c3488a0bbfad0ab059a147::getLoader()
> #4  in D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71
> PHP Fatal error:  composerRequiredc8412b933c3488a0bbfad0ab059a147(): Failed opening required 'D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer/../markbaker/complex/classes/src/functions/abs.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71
> Fatal error: composerRequiredc8412b933c3488a0bbfad0ab059a147(): Failed opening required 'D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer/../markbaker/complex/classes/src/functions/abs.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\projects\my_project\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 71

I know the problem with this package (markbaker/complex) but I can't solve this issue. Any Help?

php & laravel versions:

```
PHP 7.3.27

Laravel Framework 8.37.0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things, there is a missing file. This is highlighted on this line `./markbaker/complex/classes/src/functions/abs.php):` I would recommend you run `dump-autoload` to clear the classes ,then run `composer install`.Possibly the package's missing files will be added.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by:
`rm -rf vendor/* && composer install`